# Accept a string based on regex

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am very new to regex. I am trying to write a function which will parse a string parameter and return the corrected string. This is a basic example I took to learn this. Can anyone help me with the function in CPP?

```
string check(string str1) {
    regex re = "(.*?)";
    string s = str1;
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re);i != std::sregex_iterator();++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        cout << "the token is"<<"   "<< m.str() << endl;
        count++;
    }
}
```

- If the string contains no commas it can be passed through as is.
- Optionally the string may be quoted in that case the double quotes at the
  start and end need removing.
- If it doesn't start with a double quote then it is not a quoted string.
- A quoted string must end with a double quote otherwise it is an error.
- A quoted string can have commas in it.
- A quoted string can contain quotes as long as they are escaped ('""')

Valid examples (outermost single quotes are not part of the strings):

```
'string' -> 'string'
'str,ing' -> <ERROR>
'"string"' -> 'string'
' "string"' -> ' "string"'
'"string' -> <ERROR>
'"str,ing"' -> 'str,ing'
'"str""ing"' -> 'str"ing'
'"str"",ing"' -> 'str",ing'
```

For now I am only able to come up with above code and can't proceed further. Can someone please help? TIA.

Comment: You might be able to shoehorn regex into this task somehow, but it won't be easy. I know how to write a regex that would check whether the string is valid, but not one that could produce unquoted text. On the other hand, it will be trivial to write a simple parser that decodes the string in one pass, just looping over individual characters.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Can u please help me with regex to check whether the string is valid or not. It will be a huge help. Thanks.

Comment: Something along these lines (not tested): `|[^",][^,]*|"([^"]*"")*[^"]*"`. In English: an empty string; or a string not starting with a quote and not containing any commas; or a string surrounded by quotes, and consisting of zero or more segments of the form (anything except quotes + a pair of quotes), with another (anything except quotes) segment at the end.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, it is not working for cpp? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: My clairvoyance skills are limited. Your computer screen is hazy in my mind's eye, I find it difficult to see what you are doing and whether it's right or wrong.